# highstock animation on update

Tags: highcharts

Im looking for a way to animate a highstock when updating.
the documentation said the default value of animation is true but i couldn't see any animation on this highstock example:

```
chart : {
        events : {
            load : function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
```

full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: What are you expecting that you aren't seeing?  That jsfiddle animates for me.  Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: i mean animation like this one in highchart: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: Looks like a bug in Highstock, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2266 Thanks!